# OpenCV cv::Mat , imshow() , cv::VideoCapture is not working at runtime

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, pinvoke, dlib

Something strange is happen. I tried all the best way I can but not able to get the correct solution for it.
Rectenly I am working on one project in which dlib and open cv lib is used for face detection. The thing is I am able to achieved that but after window update I am not able to use Open Cv any function.
Meanwhile dlib is working fine for me.
I am getting now compile time error as well. But when ever I try to use even single line "cv::Mat image;"
I am getting error "dll not found".
I tried to rebuild it (64 bit) . I tried to install Window Media Features also.
I don't know whats gone wrong here.
If anyone is aware of such issue please suggest.

Comment: Even i have tried to create new project with same OpenCV libs and it's working there. But don't know why this is happened to current project. Please don't ignore this if you have any idea please help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one maybe it can work for your.

first uninstall opencv.

pip uninstall opencv-python

and the reinstall opencv

pip install opencv-python

Answer (score -2):

Can you check path environments for opencv? Did you add `OpenCVx.x\bin`? Maybe after update, binary and library paths are changed.